# I'm trying to bypass outlook alert using sendkeys, is this code correct?

Tags: vba, outlook

```
Sub Mail_Workbook()

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:06"))
Application.SendKeys "{TAB}", "false"
Application.SendKeys "{TAB}", "false"
Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"

If Val(Application.Version) >= 12 Then
If wb.FileFormat = 51 And wb.HasVBProject = True Then
MsgBox "There is VBA code in this xlsx file that will be removed if you try to send this file." & vbNewLine & _
  "Save the file first as xlsm and then try the macro again.", vbInformation
  Exit Sub
  End If
  End If

On Error Resume Next
   For I = 1 To 3
      wb.SendMail Array("email.person@company.com", "email.person2@company.com"), "Test VBA"
      If Err.Number = 0 Then Exit For
   Next I
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Well, does it do what you want it to do? Have you tried it? If not, give us a little more detail about what is or is not working.

Comment: it works fine but I have to click the "allow" button.  Which makes it not automated.  I'm wondering why the sendkeys aren't working as expected.   you can see for yourself if you copy and paste in excel module

Comment: a possible workaround is swaping .sendMail to .DisplayMail 
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
Application.SendKeys "%s"     but I haven't gotten it to work yet and I think it's because I'm using array (multiple emails)

Comment: The sending automation is restricted for security reasons. I use similar functionality for a few processes, but I just rely on the user manually bypassing this check. Nobody seems to mind given the additional amount of work the automation in general has saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take a look at Outlook Redemption:

http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm

This tool allows you to bypass Outlook's security restrictions.
Here is some sample code from the product's site:

http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/SafeMailItem.htm

It works.